# Не видна кнопка в приложении

Tags: java, android, разметка

Пишу шахматы на андроид, так все получилось, но хочу еще внизу экрана сделать кнопку "Начать сначала". Добавила кнопку в разметке `xml`, но при запуске кнопка не видна вообще. Пыталась добавить `2 Layout:` в верхнем игра, в нижнем кнопка, но это не помогло. Предполагаю, что нужно как-то не так вызывать метод `SetContentView`. Как-то надо указать ему в каком `layuot` выводить, но не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот часть кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    DrawTest drawView;
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {        
               drawView = new DrawTest(this);           
               drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);  
              // drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
               setContentView(drawView);               

               mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);            

               //нажатие на кнопку "начать сначала"
               OnClickListener oclBtnClear = new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     //расставляем фигуры заново               
                     drawView.desc1.clear_desc(null);
                 }
               };             
               mButton.setOnClickListener(oclBtnClear);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }  

   //рисует доску, тут вся логика игры
   class DrawTest extends View  {        
        Paint p;
        Desc desc1;
        ....
   }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.achess.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:minHeight="25dip"
        android:text="Начать сначала"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Класс DrawTest.java

```
package com.example.achess;
import ...


public class DrawTest extends View  {        
    Paint p;
    Desc desc1;

    public DrawTest(Context context) throws SQLException {

      super(context);
      p = new Paint();
      DBhelper dbHelper;
      try {
            // закоментарено потому что getWindowManager() не работает
             //Определяем размер крадратика доски исходя из ширины экрана
            //Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            //Point size = new Point();
            //display.getSize(size);
            //int width =  (int)Math.ceil(size.x/8);
            int width = 60;
            //для работы с БД         
            dbHelper = new DBhelper(context);           

            desc1 = new Desc(width,width,dbHelper,context); 
            //desc1.clear_desc();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

    public void Refresh_Desc(Context context){
        desc1 = null;

        //Определяем размер крадратика доски исходя из ширины экрана
        //Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        //Point size = new Point();
        //display.getSize(size);
        //int width =  (int)Math.ceil(size.x/8);
        int width = 60;

        DBhelper dbHelper;
        try {
            dbHelper = new DBhelper(context);
            // класс шахматной доски
            desc1 = new Desc(width,width,dbHelper,context); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


        // repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //рисует пустую доску
        desc1.Draw_desc(p, canvas);
        // рисует фигуры
        desc1.Draw_Figures(p, canvas);
        //рисует место куда можно поставить выделенную фигуру
        desc1.Draw_Place(p, canvas); 
    }

}
```

Comment: DrawTest что такое? В нем кнопка?

Comment: Покажи пожалуйста Ваш layout файл, я думаю, что проблему с отображение надо искать там, или хотябы принцип покажите создания drawView.

Comment: @metalurgus, да, кнопка там, иначе падало бы с nullpointer.

Comment: Исправила вопрос, теперь видно что такое drawView. Это объект класса DrawTest, который расширяет View.

Comment: @metalurgus, будьте внимательнее, потому что вопрос не я задал)

Comment: А почему нельзя просто по человечески добавить `drawView` на лаяут созданный в XML?

Comment: @Анна, это и так понятно было, все так же не видно где создаете layout

Comment: отредактировала вопрос- теперь видно разметку

Comment: @anber - вы имеете ввиду сделать  class DrawTest extends R.layout {} ? Не получается, не знаю как это сделать.. я новичок, уж простите((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала проще сделать это без извращений с `setContentView()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Где `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.yourpackage.DrawTest
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:minHeight="25dip"
        android:text="Начать сначала"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Во вторых корневой элемент в вашем примере `FrameLayout`, в нем находится кнопка, скорее всего в этом проблема - ее кто-то перекрывает. Попробуйте заменить `FrameLayout` на `LinearLayout`.

Comment: немного переделал ваш ответ, что возможно может помочь решить проблему.

Comment: @Виталий Обидейко , спасибо, com.yourpackage на свой пакет конечно же поменяла, класс DrawTest поместила в файл DrawTest.java. Но пока белый экран. Идея в целом понятна, но пока не получилось)

Comment: @Анна, я думаю, что Вам придется предоставить и класс DrawTest, иначе помочь вам будет очень сложно. ;)

Comment: @Виталий Обидейко, сейчас выложу класс DrawTest в вопрос. Сейчас белый экран и когда я делаю разметку, захожу во вкладку Graphical Layout выдает ошибку: Custom view DrawTest is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work

Comment: @Анна вы бы лучше выложили весь проект на гитхаб или архивом, чтоб можно было скачать и поклацать.

Comment: @Анна А ошибка - у вас нет конструктора с 2 и 3 параметрами.

Comment: @anber, выложила на https://cloud.mail.ru/public/HWVw/iGp5PsdSa , гитхаб пока не осилила. Ту ошибку исправила, сейчас другая - The following classes could not be instantiated:
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

Comment: @anber, пробовала в конструктор DrawTest добавить  if(!isInEditMode())  init(context); - вычитала что это помогает. Но ява не хочет понимать  init(context);

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что ответ @anber верный, но возможен вариант, что у вас кастомная вью отрисовывает все в зависимости от своего размера, и если изменить чуток ответ @anber, то все прийдет в норму:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.yourpackage.DrawTest
    android:id="@+id/drawTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:minHeight="25dip"
    android:text="Начать сначала"
    android:textStyle="normal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

А получить DrawTest можно так:

```
drawView=(DrawTest)findViewById(R.id.drawTest);
```

только не забудьте поменять com.yourpackage на ваш пакет!!!